# A type guard doesn't seem to assert a property's type inside of a for in loop. Why is that?

Tags: typescript

My IDE is throwing TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown' for `obj[key]` on line `total += obj[key]`.

From my understanding, this shouldn't happen since I'm using a typeguard with the `typeof` operator. Inside of the condition, `obj[key]` can only be a number, no? Why do I need to type assert using `as number` on the operation i.e. `total += obj[key] as number`?

```
type Fruit = {
  [key: string]: number | string;
};

const fruits: Fruit = {
  apple: 1,
  orange: 3,
  banana: "yellow",
};

function getTotal(obj: { [key: string]: unknown }): number {
  let total = 0;
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "number") {
      total += obj[key];
    }
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(getTotal(fruits));
```

Comment: `typeof obj[key] === "number"` doesn't narrow `obj` from `{ [key: string]: unknown }` or `key` from `string` - try assigning e.g. `const value = obj[key]` **then** using `value` https://tsplay.dev/m0xbPm.

Comment: thank you @jonsharpe that works, but I don't understand how... why does assign it to a variable make a difference? (sorry if I come across as obtuse with my question)...

Comment: See the linked q/a; it's a TS issue being tracked at [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  If the key you're indexing with is of type `string` then the compiler can't narrow because it can't use the type system to do so (comparing `typeof obj[key1]==="number"` wouldn't have any effect on `obj[key2]`, where both `key1` and `key2` are of type `string`, and that situation is indistinguishable from yours if all you can see are the types and not the identities). The current workaround is copying to a const.